# nginx : http2 consume more time than https in the step `Client Receive Application Data From Server`

Tags: nginx, https, http2

I am very concerned about the difference in performance between HTTPS and HTTP/2.

I am very concerned about the consumed time about each step of the process of connecting.

Include `TCP handshakes` `SSL Handshakes` and `Client sent Application Data`  `Client received Application Data`.

I made a test.

Use Nginx Server, set `port 440` : `ssl`, and `port 442` : `ssl http2`

Turn off `ssl_session_cache` and `ssl_session_tickets`, then every request would process `TCP Handshakes` and `SSL Handshakes`

```
// https url   :   ssl_session_cache off;  ssl_session_tickets off;
https://www.example.com:440/index.html


// http/2 url  :   ssl_session_cache off;  ssl_session_tickets off;
https://www.example.com:442/index.html
```

At the end, I launched the two urls above 1000 times from a android app with `OKHttp 3.8.1`.
Each request has been added Header `Connection : Close`.

At the same time, use Wireshark for capturing packets.

The statistical results are unexpected!!!

HTTP/2 consume more time than HTTPS in the step `Client Receive Application Data From Server`.

Why? I am confused. Am i wrong?   Any ideas??? Thank u.

statistical results  (Time : ms)

### [image: statistical.results]

https.url.and.http2.url

### [image: https.url.and.http2.url]

nginx.conf

[root@iZ941gs04jwZ ~]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.12.0
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/webserver/nginx --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=/root/tmp/pcre-8.35 --with-http_v2_module --with-openssl=../openssl-1.0.2l

[image: nginx.conf]

Comment: The comparison is between HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, both are using HTTPS! Even more I would say that you compare nginx's +okHTTP's implementations of HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2...

Comment: yes, and what's the point?

Comment: that your question doesn't say so, it makes it sound like you compare HTTPS with HTTP/2...

Comment: It's 'compare HTTPS with HTTP/2' really.